# Firestore EventListener causes Null Exception when I Delete Fields

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, event-listener

I am registering an event listener inside one method.

```
public void listenForUpdates(){

       final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("teams").document(selectedTeam);
        ListenerRegistration registration = docRef.addSnapshotListener(PokerActivity.this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override

[snip]

        //registration.remove();
    }
```

Then in a different method I have to delete two arrays in their entirity from my Firestore database.

```
    public void undoClicked(View view) {
                    db.collection("teams").document(selectedTeam).update("selectedCards", FieldValue.delete());
                    db.collection("teams").document(selectedTeam).update("players", FieldValue.delete());
```

My problem, is:

1. When I delete the `selectedCards` and `players` arrays, the Event Listener throws a null object reference (At least I think that is the cause).

```
2019-05-19 16:26:32.974 14243-14243/com.example.scrumpoker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.scrumpoker, PID: 14243
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.scrumpoker.PokerActivity$4.onEvent(PokerActivity.java:302)
        at com.example.scrumpoker.PokerActivity$4.onEvent(PokerActivity.java:290)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:515)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ExecutorEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ExecutorEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

2. But if I enable `registration.remove();` for the listener in my `listenForUpdates()` method , then my app does not monitor the database for changes.

I seem to be caught between a rock and a hard place!

How can I have the Event Listener, but then disable it before deleting my arrays - without trying to put all my code into one method?

OR - How can I empty my arrays without deleting them completely from the Firestore database?

Answer (score 0):

In your listener you can use `exists()` to check if there is data or not, example:

```
ListenerRegistration registration = docRef.addSnapshotListener(PokerActivity.this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
  @Override
    public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, 
    FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
     if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(PokerActivity.this, "Current data:" + 
      documentSnapshot.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
       Toast.makeText(PokerActivity.this,"no data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
 }
});
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#exists()):

> `public boolean exists ()`
>
> Returns
>   true if the document existed in this snapshot.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, because there is other data in the document in addition to the two Arrays I want to delete. I am using exists() at the moment.

Comment: This is my DB Sttructure. I want to delete 'players' and 'selectedCards' arrays.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/RqS47JxTk5V9qSLC7

Comment: If there is other documents in the collection then how are u getting nullpointerexception

Comment: I'm getting a "null object reference"

Comment: Got It! I needed to instantiate my ListenerRegistration registration; variable outside the method, and change the scope of registration.remove(); within the method. Fixed! Thanks for your help @Peter Haddad

Comment: Great! If my answer helped you then please upvote it and mark it as correct so other users can know that it is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the `ListenerRegistration registration;` variable outside the method, and change the scope of `registration.remove();` within the method.